# Updates to existing custom Joomla component

Tags: joomla, components

I am running Joomla 3.1.5.  I have a custom component installed and I have made some minor changes to some of the files.   How do I create an uploadable/installable zip file to install these changes to my production Joomla site?

Comment: Change the name of the template in the xml file and then just zip it up and install.  If you have just made minor changes it may be easier to copy the old template in the template manager UI and then just upload the files you changed.

Comment: I think I might just create a fresh install, and remove/re-install what I had.  I have like so many xml template files, I don't even know how to rename them.

Comment: No ... the templateDetails.xml file, that tells the installer where to put the files, you don't want to overwrite the old ones.

Comment: I'm sorry for some reason I thought you had a template, with a component you need to also rename the places where the folders are designated if you want to make it under a new name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disregard the discussion on templates in the comments above.

You don't need to rename your component it seems.

**If you need to install on a single site:**

- on the prodution site, install the installer you first installed on
  your development site
- sync the files with a version control system
  such as git / rsync / scp / sftp / ftp whichever you're most
  comfortable with

**If you need to install on multiple sites:**

You need to repackage it, and add to the xml manifest any files/folders you added.

Simply explode the original zip installer somewhere on your drive, and figure out the folder structure (could be admin,site,media for example).

For each browse the custom_component_name.xml section and ensure it contains the files you added, if any.

Then copy the updated files over the folder structure, zip it, and upload it to production.

Once you do this the component will be registered in the other Joomla installation. You can also keep the copies aligned between the two servers with a code versioning system such as git.

If it's a component you plan on distributing, create a script to package it, look at the Joomla docs there's plenty of info, you could use a bash script, phing, ant, maven, choose one that suits you any will do the job